# Getting attribute from XML with my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I try to read a specific value of a XML feed. Evertyhing is working but I want to read the "StartTime=" value too.

This is the XML:

```
<Program StartTime="17:00:00" EndTime="17:30:00">
<Name>name</Name>
</Program>
```

And this is the code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",

        error: function (e) {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file");
            console.log("XML reading Failed: ", e);
        },

        success: function (response) {


            $("ul").children().remove();

            $(response).find("Program").each(function () {
                var _name = 'Program: ' + $(this).find('Name').text();
                console.log(_name);
                var _time = 'Time: ' + $(this).find('StartDateTime').text();

                // add content to the HTML
                $("ul").append('<li>' + _name + '</li>');
                $("ul").append('<li>' + _time + '</li>');

            });
        }
    });
}
```

I found some interesting information, but I can't actually use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StartTime` is an *attribute* of `<Program>`,  not an element/node inside it.  `find()` is for elements that are descendants.

Use `attr()` instead

Try:

```
var _time = 'Time: ' + $(this).attr('StartDate')
```